# Is "of" interchangeable for "by" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The headline is:

'Are Centrists in the Thrall of Right-Wing Propaganda?'

I can only understand this if I swap "of" for "by" like:

'Are Centrists in the Thrall BY Right-Wing Propaganda?'

is it the same?

Comment: The headline is correct. You can't use 'by'. People are said to be **in the thrall of** or **in thrall to** someone or something. We can say someone is 'enthralled by', meaning 'very interested in', someone or something, but that's a different meaning.

Comment: This question could easily be answered by looking in a good dictionary. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thrall

Comment: Let me ask you: In Portuguese can you switch por and de?

Comment: What @JavaLatte said. The only real issue here is that some learners (and even some native speakers) might confuse the *spoken* versions of #1 *He's **in thrall to** her* and #2 *He's **enthralled by** her*. Note - you might well say that those two utterances should mean the same thing, but actually we normally reserve #1 for the *literal* sense (she holds power over him; he must obey her every command), and #2 for the *metaphoric* sense (he's captivated / enchanted / fascinated by her).

Answer (score 2):

**The headline is correct. Substituting "by" is incorrect.**

["in thrall" is a standard phrase.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20thrall) It can take the preposition "to", or it can be possessive. The examples given are:

> He was completely in thrall to her.

> He was completely in her thrall.

Possessives can usually be rewritten in an "of" form, so you could also write:

> He was completely in the thrall of her.

You use the definite article because you are referring to a specific "thrall", the one that is hers, rather than thrall in general.

"By" should not be used with thrall. While the construct is seen, I suspect it is an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) for the similar-sounding:

> He is completely *[enthralled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enthrall)* by her.

See also the helpful answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337539/in-thrall-to-vs-in-the-thrall-of